# Kernel of compact operators

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory

Since a compact operator $K$ on an infinite dimensional separable Hilbert space $H$ can't be invertible, the spectrum of $K$ must contain zero $0\in \mbox{sp}(K)$. However, $K$ could be injective (e.g. if $K$ is strictly positive).  Hence, all the elements in the spectrum $\mbox{sp}(K)$ are eigenvalues of $K$, except perhaps zero. Is this true? ...I'm a little confused about this, since I've always heard that all the elements in the spectrum of a compact operator must be eigenvalues.

Comment: Yes, this is true. The spectrum of a compact operator is the union of the set of eigenvalues and the point 0.

Comment: ... but/and this should be moved to Math Stack Exchange...

Answer (score 4):

All the *non-zero* points of the spectrum of a compact operator are eigenvalues, yes, and, yes, in an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space $0$ is always in the spectrum, being an accumulation point of the non-zero spectrum.

$0$ may or may not be an eigenvalue, depending on the operator. The operator on $\ell^2$ that sends $e_n\to e_n/n$ is compact, and $0$ is not an eigenvalue, though $0$ is in the spectrum. And it is also easy to make compact operators with $0$ as an eigenvalue.

(... but this should be moved to Math Stack Exchange...)